# How to add a inline image using javamail?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I want to send a inline image to an email. I tried almost all possible ways, but no luck.

I am able to add images as inline, but they were also appearing in attachments, so I am not able to avoid this attachment.

```
messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            String htmlText = "<H1>This is the image: </H1><img src=\"cid:image\">";
            ((MimeBodyPart) messageBodyPart).setText(htmlText, null, "html");
            mp.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // second part (the image)
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            String filePath = "abc.png";
            ((MimeBodyPart) messageBodyPart).attachFile(filePath, "image/png", "base64");
            ((MimeBodyPart) messageBodyPart).setContentID("<image>");
            mp.addBodyPart( messageBodyPart );
```

I also tried using `messageBodyPart.setDisposition( MimePart.INLINE );`, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a multipart/related message.  The [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#sendmpr) has an example.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using the MimeMessageHelper. It will make your life a bunch easier

```
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper( mimeMessage, true );
helper.setText( htmlText, true );
helper.addInline( "image", signatureImage ); // image here is the cid
```